# Why is my for-loop printing on every other line and not every line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, printing

My function is:

```
def draw_map():
    for row in list:
        for tile in row:
            print(tile, end=' ')
        print('\n')
```

Output is:

```
                  _ _ _       o

                /       \   O

                \       /

                  ‾ ‾ ‾
```

Output should be:

```
                  _ _ _       o
                /       \   O
                \       /
                  ‾ ‾ ‾
```

Edit: Removing print('\n') makes the output:

```
                      _ _ _       o                             /\   O                               \       /          ‾ ‾ ‾
```

So why is the one \n making it print on every other line?

Comment: It's helpful to include a fully-reproducible example so we can test this on our end. What is the value of `list` here? (note also that `list` is a keyword in Python and thus shouldn't be used as a variable name. You could use something like `my_list` instead if you like, or a more descriptive name based on the contents of the list)

Comment: 1) `list` is a key word, you shouldn't use it as a variable. 2) You should pass your list not use a global variable.

Comment: It isn't "list" in my code, I made it "list" to simplify my question, sorry about that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`print` has `end="\n"` by default, so doing `print("\n")` prints *two* newlines. I think you just mean to do `print()`.

Comment: Works perfectly, I will accept your answer when the stack overflow time limit is up. Thank you!